# System Center Operations Manager 2007 R2 install error 25154

Tags: sql-server-2008, scom

While installing SCOM 07 R2 Database component on our DB server I get this error...

[image]

I've gotten the same error on the following configurations.

- Windows Server 2003 & SQL Server 2008 SP1
- Windows Server 2008 & SQL Server 2008 SP2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a lot of searching (as I'm sure you did), and wasn't able to find any posts that had the same error as you.  That being said, I ran across [this](http://www.mytechnet.org/archives/310).  It goes over installing the database component for SCOM.  The fact that it's failing for you across multiple environments leads me to believe its a configuration issue.

HTH